# My sfml project crashes after ~10 seconds

Tags: c++, sfml

I have a problem with my sfml project in c++. After compiling and running this simple code, i start using my mouse in the window (the code is a very simple pathfinding algorithm, in which, where i click, that's where the "ch" texture goes) and after aprox. 10 or so seconds the window stops responding. The only time when the program doesn't crash is when i run it in debug mode. i had this problem some time ago with a bigger project, but because of this problem i gave up on it. I believe that the program crashing has somthing to do with using the mouse, because in the bigger project i once started and crashed in the same way I also used the sfml mouse functions, and when compiled and ran in debug mode, it didn't crash. I'm programming in Code::Blocks version:13.12, and the SFML library i'm not sure what version. I have no idea why this happens, so ask you for help whith this problem. Thanks:D

The code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace sf;

int main()
{
RenderWindow win(VideoMode(700,700),"test");

float x=10,y=10;
int mx=x,my=y;
int mxo,myo;

Texture t;
t.loadFromFile("char.png");
Sprite ch;
ch.setTexture(t);

ch.setPosition(x,y);

while(win.isOpen())
{
    win.clear();
    if(Mouse::isButtonPressed(Mouse::Left))
    {
        mx=Mouse::getPosition(win).x;
        my=Mouse::getPosition(win).y;
    }
        if(x!=mx)
        {
            if(mx>x)
            {
                x++;
            }
            if(mx<x)
            {
                x--;
            }
            Sleep(2);
        }
        if(y!=my)
        {
            if(my>y)
            {
                y++;
            }
            if(my<y)
            {
                y--;
            }
            Sleep(2);
        }

        ch.setPosition(x,y);
        win.draw(ch);
    win.display();
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? Also you don't seem to poll events from render window.

Comment: You aren't responding to windows events. Look at the examples in [the documentation](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1RenderWindow.php)

Comment: I changed the part where the position of that mouse i taken to an event and it works great. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have blocking sleeps in the main event loop, and are not handling events.

This makes the OS *think* that the program is unresponsive, and it tells you *that*.

It didn't actually crash.

Comment: I'm using sleeps beacause if not the program does everything too fast and i wanted to see the path that the program calculates. But i changed the part in where the position of the mouse is taken to an event and now works great. Thank you for your help:D